# Get ASCII from char from string

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have a loop with `i` incrementing through a string, and I want to print that character, but its ASCII code.

```
myString = "90210";
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(myString.charAt(i));
}
```

To output:

```
57
48
50
49
48
```

Obviously `charAt()` doesn't do this, but I need another method to append to it to get my desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast to an `int` so that you get the numerical value of the `char`, which consequently uses the overloaded `println(int)` method

```
System.out.println((int)myString.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(myString.charAt(i) - '\0');
System.out.println(myString.charAt(i) - 0);
```

Comment: That's a pretty curious way to cast.

Comment: For curious people, this works because a `char (op) char`, where `op` is any of the `+, -, *, /, %` operators, results in an `int` value. This is actually true for all numeric types smaller or equal to an `int`.